# how to return query in postgresql function

Tags: json, postgresql

I've PostgreSQL function with `json` data object and I need to return some values
this is my function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."insert_from_json"("in_json_txt" json)
      RETURNS "pg_catalog"."void" AS $BODY$
      INSERT INTO json_test2 (name, age, location_id)
    WITH t1 AS (
         SELECT (rec->>'name')::text , (rec->>'age')::integer  FROM
      json_array_elements(in_json_txt->'data') rec
        
        ),t2 AS (
        WITH my_v_table ( jsonblob ) AS ( VALUES ( in_json_txt:: jsonb ) ) 
        
        SELECT
    ((my_v_table.jsonblob ->> 'Store_IntegrationCode')::numeric) as store_id
    FROM my_v_table
        )
        
        SELECT * from t1,t2
        
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
      COST 100
```

when I use returns query I got error :(

this is call statement

```
    select insert_from_json('{
        "Customer_IntegrationCode": "558889999",
        "XretialOrderCode": "000020430",
        "ShippingAddress": "Cairo, Nasr City, 01128777733",
        "ShippingAddress_IntegrationCode": null,
        "PaymentOption": 1,
        "CreationDate": "2021-01-04T07:38:57.033Z",
        "Total": 73.0,
        "Currency": "EGP",
        "Note": null,
        "ShippingCost": 15.0,
        "CODFee": 25.0,
        "ShipmentProvider": null, 
        "Plateform": 1, 
        "SubTotal": 33.0,
        "TotalDiscountAmount_PerOrderLevel": 0,
        "OriginalSubTotal": 33.0,
        "TaxPercentage": null,
        "TaxValue": null,
        "Store_IntegrationCode": "1234567",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "12345678",
                "age": "23456789",
                "Qty": 3,
                "UnitPrice": 11.0,
                "NetPrice": 11.0,
                "SKUDiscount": 0,
                "Total": 33.0,
                "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
                "SubTotal": 33.0
                
            },
                    {
                "name": "999999",
                "age": "988888",
                "Qty": 3,
                "UnitPrice": 11.0,
                "NetPrice": 11.0,
                "SKUDiscount": 0,
                "Total": 33.0,
                "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
                "SubTotal": 33.0
                
            }
        ]
    }
    ')
```

when I add return query to function I got this error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN"
> LINE 18:  RETURN query SELECT * from t1,t2

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: after add Return query
   SELECT * from t1,t2 to function i got this error ,, > ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Return"
LINE 19:   Return query

Comment: this error when i create a function with return not when i call it

Comment: Then add the JSON which will be passed.

Comment: ok i updated rhe post check it pls

Comment: But there is no ` RETURN query SELECT * from t1,t2` statement in the function posted in the question. also posted function is perfectly OK you can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e56e8a585c0b7268740110089c3b4a40). It seems the function definition posted in question and you are running is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228482/discussion-between-tarek-ramadan-and-akhilesh-mishra).

Comment: Also note that your return type is `void` so you can't use `return query`. If you want to return something then please mention it in the question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return the values from a function returning `VOID`.
If you want to return the rows after insertion you can try below mentioned function definition:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."insert_from_json"("in_json_txt" json)
  RETURNS 
  table (name_ text, age_ int, location_ numeric)
  AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  INSERT INTO json_test2 (name, age, location_id)
(WITH t1 AS (
     SELECT (rec->>'name')::text , (rec->>'age')::integer  FROM
  json_array_elements(in_json_txt->'data') rec
    ),t2 AS (
    WITH my_v_table ( jsonblob ) AS ( VALUES ( in_json_txt:: jsonb ) ) 
    
    SELECT
((my_v_table.jsonblob ->> 'Store_IntegrationCode')::numeric) as store_id
FROM my_v_table
    )
    SELECT * from t1,t2
    )
    RETURNING name, age, location_id;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a8c86c95e1b08092a84cce3df67201d5)

Even same thing you can write in more shorter and simpler way like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."insert_from_json"("in_json_txt" json)
  RETURNS 
  table (name_ text, age_ int, location_ numeric)
  AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  INSERT INTO json_test2 (name, age, location_id)
  SELECT 
  (rec->>'name')::text, (rec->>'age')::integer, (in_json_txt->>'Store_IntegrationCode')::numeric   
  FROM json_array_elements(in_json_txt->'data') rec
  RETURNING name, age, location_id;

    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ca71308e55a7827cc5d7f1354a69cfd8)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the function to just an "Insert ... Returning" by 'converting' to SQL function.

```
create or replace function insert_from_json(in_json_txt json)
  returns setof json_test2
 language sql 
as $$
  insert into json_test2 (name, age, location)
     select (rec->>'name')::text
          , (rec->>'age')::integer
          , (in_json_txt->>'Store_IntegrationCode')::numeric   
       from json_array_elements(in_json_txt->'data') rec
  returning *;
$$;
```

See [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ffdc13dd034a9d59d7dc1faa511bf7b8)